# Display image as background processing

Tags: java, image, processing

I am trying to use an image as the background in java processing, but this code gives me the error: "The file "cave_entrance.jpg" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable."

This is the code I have:

```
public class Main extends PApplet{

    public void setup(){
        size(900,700);
        background(0);
    }// setup

    public void draw(){
        PImage background = loadImage("cave_entrance.jpg");
        background(background);
    }// draw

}// Main
```

I have the file cave_entrance.jpg in

```
Project
    data
        cave_entrance.jpg
```

Comment: You should probably make ```PImage backround``` available for the whole sketch and load it once in ```setup()``` (rather than multiple times per second in draw())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check where exatcly to place this file by calling:

```
println(dataPath(""));
```

Comment: Thanks!  The place it needed to be in was Project\bin\data

Answer (score 1):

From the Processing [documentation for the `dataPath()` function](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#dataPath-java.lang.String-):

> **This function almost certainly does not do the thing you want it to.** The data path is handled differently on each platform, and should not be considered a location to write files. **It should also not be assumed that this location can be read from or listed.** This function is used internally as a possible location for reading files. It's still "public" as a holdover from earlier code.
>
> Libraries should use createInput() to get an InputStream or createOutput() to get an OutputStream. sketchPath() can be used to get a location relative to the sketch. **Again, do not use this to get relative locations of files.** You'll be disappointed when your app runs on different platforms.

It also sounds strange that a path includes the `bin` directory. I would expect any path in your sketch to be relative to the `bin` directory, so you shouldn't need to use an absolute path to get into that directory.

Since you aren't using the Processing editor, you have to add your `data` directory to your `source` path. If you're in eclipse, you can do this just by copying your `data` directory into the `src` directory. This is a much better solution than manually copying files into your `bin` directory, since eclipse can (and will) delete those files without warning.

Comment: You certainly give convincing reasons for why it shouldn't be in bin, but it only works if the data folder is in bin, and the image file is in data

Comment: @mCoder My argument is not that it shouldn't be in `bin`, it's that you shouldn't place it in `bin` yourself. You should let eclipse (or whatever you're using) move it for you, by placing it into your `src` directory.